# TFS in VS2017 hanging up and freezing

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, source-control-explorer

For the past week or so I've been having an issue with the Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio 2017. It now takes a minute or more to expand a folder, and when I right-click -> Get Latest Version it completely freezes and I have to manually close the program with the Task Manager.

I have already tried removing and re-adding the connection to our TFS server. Others on my team are using the same version of VS2017 and the same TFS server without issue. I've uninstalled all extensions and that didn't help either. Short of a complete reinstall, what can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: My first instinct would be to clear workspace cache, see this older article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsalm/2013/12/17/how-to-clear-the-tfs-cache-on-client-machines/

Comment: Just try to clean the workspace and client caches as Mike mentioned, if you select uninstall/reinstall, make sure you have completely uninstalled VS including all components, registry key, caches etc. You can also check the event viewer, are there any error messages there for your troubleshoot.

Comment: I tried deleting the cache and that didn't work, so I tried uninstalling every VS program and helper I could find and re-installing. That didn't work either. So I wonder if it's something to do with our TFS server - but like I said in my original question, other team members are using this server without any issues. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio, I finally figured it out.

I deleted all of the files I had downloaded from TFS locally. After I did that TFS started working without any problems again.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and tried clearing the cache as per below link but didn't work.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsalm/2013/12/17/how-to-clear-the-tfs-cache-on-client-machines/

Deleting workspace did the trick.

1. Open Team Explorer
2. Click Source Control Explorer
3. In the nav bar of the tool window there is a drop down labeled "Workspaces".
4. Extend it and click on the "Workspaces..." option (yeah, a bit un-intuitive)
5. The "Manage Workspaces" window comes up. Click edit and you can add / remove / edit your workspace